# Two definitions of $QMA$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, quantum-information, qma

In this question, I am trying to understand the equivalence between the following two definitions of the complexity class **QMA**.

In [Quantum Computational Complexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3401), John Watrous defines the class **QMA** as follows.

> Let $A = (A_{yes}, A_{no})$ be a promise problem, let $p$ be a
>   polynomial-bounded function, and let $a, b: \mathbb{N} \to [0, 1]$ be
>   functions. Then $A \in \text{QMA}_p (a, b)$ if and only if there
>   exists a polynomial-time generated family of circuits $Q = \left\{Q_n
>  : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, where each circuit $Q_n$ takes $n + p
>  (n)$ input qubits and produces one output qubit, with the following
>   properties:
>
> 1. *Completeness*. For all $x \in A_{yes}$, there exists a $p (|x|)$-qubit quantum state $\rho$ such that $Pr[Q \text{ accepts } (x,
>     \rho)] \ge a (|x|)$.
> 2. *Soundness*. For all $x \in A_{no}$ and all $p(|x|)$-qubit quantum states $\rho$ it holds that $Pr[Q \text{ accepts } (x, \rho)] \le
>     b(|x|)$.
>
> Also define $\text{QMA} = \bigcup_p \text{QMA}_p (2/3, 1/3)$, where
>   the union is over all polynomial-bounded functions $p$.

In [Classical and Quantum Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821832298), Kitaev et al defined the same class (named as **BQNP**) as follows.

> A function $F:\mathbb{B}^n \to \left\{0, 1,
>  \text{"undefined"}\right\}$ belongs to the class **BQNP** if there
>   exits a polynomial class algorithm that computes a function $x \mapsto
>  Z(x)$, where $Z(x)$ is a description of a quantum circuit, realizing
>   an operator $U_x : \mathcal{B}^{\otimes N_x} \to \mathcal{B}^{\otimes
>  N_x}$ such that
>
> $$ F(x) = 1 \Longrightarrow \exists |\xi\rangle  \in
>  \mathcal{B}^{\otimes m_x} \mathbf{P} \left(U_x |\xi\rangle \otimes
>  |0^{N_x - m_x}\rangle, \mathcal{M}\right) \ge p_1,\\ F(x) = 0
>  \Longrightarrow \forall |\xi\rangle  \in \mathcal{B}^{\otimes m_x}
>  \mathbf{P} \left(U_x |\xi\rangle \otimes |0^{N_x - m_x}\rangle,
>  \mathcal{M}\right) \le p_0. $$
>
> Here $\mathcal{M} = \mathbb{C}\left(|1\rangle\right) \otimes
>  \mathcal{B}^{\otimes (N_x - 1)}$, and  $p_0, p_1$ satisfy the
>   condition $p_1 - p_0 \ge \Omega (n^{-\alpha})$ for some constant
>   $\alpha > 0$. The quantifiers of $|\xi\rangle$ include only vectors of
>   unit length. The *quantum probability* $\mathbf{P}(\cdot, \cdot)$ is
>   defined as follows.
>
> For a quantum state given by a density matrix $\rho$ and a subspace
>   $\mathcal{M}$, the probability of the event $\mathcal{M}$ equals
>   $\mathbf{P}(\rho, \mathcal{M}) = Tr(\rho\Pi_\mathcal{M})$. Here,
>   $\Pi_{\mathcal{M}}$ denotes the operator of orthogonal projection onto
>   the subspace $\mathcal{M}$.

**My question:**

With $F:\mathbb{B}^n \to \left\{0, 1,
 \text{"undefined"}\right\}$ i.e. not having a promise problem, do Kitaev et al define a broader class of problems?

Comment: The second definition is the same as the first by defining the function to be undefined outside the promised set. In other words F(x) = "undefined" according to the second definition if and only if x is not contained in $A_\mathrm{yes} \cup A_\mathrm{no}$. Notice that in the second definition there is no condition on the algorithm when x is undefined.

Comment: @RobinKothari, makes sense.